# how to calculate height of a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have two div one for name and another is for price. I have given height of first div as auto, Because name can be of any height . Now I want to provide same height of first div to second div so that both div could have same height. 
i used height() method of jquery but its not giving height value in pixel/number, i think it simply return "auto" as its return value. I want height of first div in pixel/number even though I have set its value as "auto".
for reference you can visit my site here http://foonty.com/index.php/jewellary/rings.html

Comment: `.height()` returns real (calculated) height in pixels

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     var height = $("#Div1")[0].clientHeight;
  $("#Div2").css('height', height+'px');
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3y2Lg0aj/)

Using Loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var height = $("#Div"+[i])[0].clientHeight;
        $("#PDiv"+[i]).css('height', height + 'px');
    }
});
```

## [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/036gjuk5/)

Comment: i ve applied ur code its working fine but only for the first products name and its price. you have to know one thing that same divs is repeating for each products. for exapmple for 10 products it will repeat 10 times. you can check here http://foonty.com/index.php/jewellary/rings.html

Comment: you need to apply for all the divs or using for loop you can acheive it

Comment: thanks for replying me.can you provide another demo using for loop ?